# Java 11 + Java FX: "Отсутствуют необходимые для запуска приложения runtime и компоненты" при запуске собранного JAR-файла

Tags: java, javafx, maven, java-11

После многочисленных вопросов по Maven и Ваших замечательных ответов на них я благополучно собрал jar-файл элементарного приложения с использованием **Java 11**, **Spring 5.1** и **Java FX**. Но JAR-файл запустился со следующей ошибкой:

```
"Отсутствует необходимые для запуска приложения runtime и компоненты JavaFX"
```

Ответ на вопрос наверняка кроется в **pom.xml**, но я на всякий случай приведу и Java-код.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>OTCJA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.EntryPoint</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/libs
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.example.EntryPoint</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**EntryPoint.java**

Spring, конечно же, отношения к данному вопросу не имеет и ошибка едва ли связана с ним, но у меня была задача создать минимальную основу приложения с использованием технологий **Java 11**, **Spring 5.1** и **Java FX**, потому пока кода мало, приведу его полностью.

```
package com.example;

import com.example.beans.TestSpringBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class EntryPoint extends javafx.application.Application {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
    TestSpringBean testSpringBean = (TestSpringBean) applicationContext.getBean("testSpringBean");
    System.out.println(testSpringBean.getTestString());
    launch();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX11!");
    Scene scene = new Scene(label, 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: А как именно запускаете?

Comment: В IntelIJ IDEA кликаю правой кнопкой мыши по собранному JAR-файлу и в меню выбираю пункт **Run AppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**. При этом в окне Run автоматически вводится команда `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-31j -jar "C:\Users\Username\Documents\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\AppName\target\AppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"`.

Comment: очевидное решение - запускать с параметром --module-path=здесь перечислить javafx модули, какие именно модули нужны - не знаю, как сделать это нормально в Idea тоже не подскажу

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX

Comment: использовать таким образом `Spring` бэд практика.

Comment: @Maxim, благодарю Вас за подсказку! Первый же вопрос, который у меня возникает. Ну хорошо, я на своём компьютере могу все эти пути прописать и так далее. Но что в случае с создании приложений на заказ, когда подразумевается запуск приложения на других машинах? Так тоже придётся какие-то настройки делать помимо помимо установки JVM?

Comment: @Tsyklop, подскажите пожалуйста, почему такое использование Spring не приветствуется и как правильно совместить JavaFX и Spring.

Comment: @БоковГлеб У меня еще до java 9 руки не дошли посмотреть, поэтому знания исключительно теоретические, но думаю ответ на этот квест кроется в том, что JVM11 на машину заказчика не установить по причине того, что jre10 была последней, для 11 и последующих версий их не будет. Используется другой механизм доставки, полагаю в новый запускатор и предлагается зашить эти аргументы.

Comment: @Tsyklop, бэд практика связана с настройкой через xml или что-то еще?

Comment: "..как правильно совместить JavaFX и Spring" а какую именно функциональность Spring вы собираетесь использовать в приложении c JavaFX? Мне кажется Spring вам совсем не нужен. А если вы ещё замените Java 11 на Java 8, то у вас автоматически отпадут все проблемы с запуском и дистрибуцией готового приложения.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, во-первых, инъекцию зависимостей (для этого я уже добавил spring-context). Далее - возможность не тратить время на рутинные задачи: нужны удобные инструменты для работы с локальной базой данный и файлами, а также возможность отправлять HTTP-запросы и принимать ответы. Конечно, Spring - это не единственное решение, но я выбрал именно данный фреймворк для решения типовых задач разработки приложений.